# CSS Grid breakout for page title

Tags: css-grid

I am using a css grid (previously been using flexbox) and I am trying to work out how to break out of a css grid for my page title. My site structure looks like this:

[image: site-structure]

Here is the css:

```
.site {
  column-gap: $sidebar-gap;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto ($sidebar-width);   // site structure
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;              // sticky header & footer
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "main sidebar"
    "footer footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.site-main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.widget-area {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
body
└── div (#page .site)
    ├── header (#masthead .site-header)
    |   ├── div (.site-branding)
    |   |   ├── a (.logo)
    |   |   └── p (.site-description)
    |   ├── nav (#site-navigation .main-navigation)
    |   |   ├── button (.menu-toggle)
    |   |   ├── div (#menu-desktop-container .menu-desktop-container)
    |   |   └── div (#menu-mobile-container .menu-mobile-container)
    |   └── div (.head-search)
    |
    ├── main (#primary .site-main)
    |   └── article (.module)
    |       ├── div (.page-head)
    |       |   ├── h1 (.page-title)
    |       |   └── div (.page-meta)
    |       └── div (.page-content)
    |           └── <page content goes here>
    |
    ├── aside (#secondary .widget-area)
    |   └── <content> (section)
    |
    └── footer (#colophon .site-footer)
        ├── div (.footer-widgets)
        ├── nav (.footer-navigation)
        |   └── div (#menu-footer-container .menu-footer-container)
        └── div (.site-info)
```

What I am trying to achieve is the `.page-head` div to breakout of the css grid and span across the entire width of the page. From here I would like the sidebar (i.e. `.widget-area`) to commence below the `.page-head`. Typically in the past when using flexbox I would achieve this would using `position: absolute` on the `.page-head` which has a fixed height. I would then just add `margin-top` to the `.widget-area` to be the same as the `.page-head` site.

I tried this in CSS grid and this doesn't work. This is what I am trying to achieve visually:

[image: example-of-what-I-need-to-achieve]

I am not able to change the HTML structure - i.e. the obvious thing would be to move the sidebar (`.widget-area`) within main (`.site-main`), then this would be super easy to achieve. As this is a Wordpress theme, this is not possible.

Comment: Ok I may have answered my own question. Not sure if there is a better way, but this is what I came up with playing around in Codepen. Here is the [link to the pen](https://codepen.io/9to5IT/pen/KKXXqgm) in Codeine so you can test it yourself... See the `SOLUTION TESTING` section of the SCSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a grid inside a grid and this will do the job :

[image]

To be sure the layout meet your requirements I use the html of your codepen.

Test the snippet below :

```css
.site {
  column-gap: 40px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto (25%);
  grid-template-rows: auto 3rem 1fr auto;
}

header {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.site-main {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.widget-area {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
}

footer {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
article {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 40px;
  grid-template-columns: auto (25%);
  grid-template-rows: 3rem 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.page-head {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.page-content {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.site {
  padding: 0 10px;  
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.page-content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

h1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.widget-area {
  border: 1px solid green;
  
  .module {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <header>Header</header>
  
  <main class="site-main">
    <article class="module">
      <div class="page-head">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="page-content">
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
  
  <aside class="widget-area">
    <div class="module">Widget 1</div>
    <div class="module">Widget 2</div>
    <div class="module">Widget 3</div>
  </aside>

  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Or check the Codepen here : https://codepen.io/BSO__/pen/ZEXvgXR

Comment: wow thanks very much, so much to learn using CSS Grid... this is so much easier that what I ended up doing with fixed heights, etc. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :)